# rails authlogic can't find current_user (undefined) after login redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I've got a rails app where I'm using a combination of authlogic and cancan.

when I check for `current_user` in the app, I always get `undefined variable or method 'current_user'`

I can get the `current_user` to display from my UserSessions controller if I use

```
def create
   @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

   if @user_session.save
       return render :json => current_user
   end
end
```

however, if in my Home controller, I try

```
def index
   return render :json => current_user
end
```

I get the `undefined` error.

In my Application Helper, I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  private

  def current_user_session
    return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
    @current_user_session = UserSession.find
  end

  def current_user
    return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
    @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  end
end
```

so it seems to me the session is being created, but rails is unable to find it again. 
Can anybody shed some light on why that is?

I've gone through the Ryan Bates tutorial, and a few others, but it all seems the same to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question, but I ended up stripping out authlogic and moved to devise. It was much faster to make the change than all the time I spent trying to debug the issue in authlogic.